# need help updating laptop

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, updates

So I tried to install encryption third party software and I messed up. I keep getting this message when trying you sudo apt-get update

```
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'medibuntu.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type '<meta' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

What can I do to fix this situation?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Medibuntu indicates to me it no longer exists, so I'd just remove the entries/file.  I didn't explore beyond the ubuntu.wiki's, and have no special knowledge, so I'd remove it unless you want to view the file and correct the errors (eg. line 3 of specified file looks wrong from message)

Comment: You need to remove those files: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu*`. The medibuntu repository has been dead for years.

Comment: how do i remove those errors? every time I type in sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu* or something to similar effect it says either no file or directory.

Comment: fixed it guys thanks again you guys are the best thank you again I used the following command by MikeWhatever

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the multiple medibuntu entries with the following command:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu*
```